# vuejs FormData doesn't send json

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource, nuxt.js

I'm not quite sure what's causing it, but I'm using nuxtjs and attempting to send `username` and `password` to my Go server in json form. This is my vue code:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Login</h1>
   <div>
    <label for="username" >Username</label>
    <input class="input-block" type="text" v-model="username">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password" >Password</label>
    <input class="input-block" type="password" v-model="password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="login">Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)

var loginURL = 'http://localhost:5000/login'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      username: [],
      password: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login: function () {
      NProgress.start()
      var formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('username', this.username)
      formData.append('password', this.password)
      this.$http.post(loginURL, formData, {emulateJSON: true}).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      }, response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have also tried to remove `{emulateJSON: true}` but the result is the same.

The server Go code looks like this:

```
func LoginPOST(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  var loginForm struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
  }
  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
  if err != nil {
    // return 422
    return
  }
  fmt.Println("body string:", string(body))
  err = json.Unmarshal(body, &loginForm)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    // return 422
    return
  }
  ...
}
```

The `json.Unmarshal` error will print: `invalid character '-' in numeric literal`, and that's because the r.Body is:

```
body string: -----------------------------10632500131211292840295750524
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

MYUSERNAME
-----------------------------10632500131211292840295750524
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

MYPASSWORD
-----------------------------10632500131211292840295750524--
```

I'm quite sure the Go code is correct, but I can't figure out why vue-resource sends the FormData in that way. I'd appreciate if someone could show how to send json and nothing else in the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NProgress.start()
      var formData = {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      }
      this.$http.post(loginURL, formData).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      }, response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
```

A regualr formdata object from the browser is never json encoded as far as i know. So just define a json object and everything should be fine.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! I could've sworn I saw two different places mention FormData used json by default :p

Comment: Glad to help you. I know this situation very well myself ;)